# tool to see/snoop communication between Java application and printer

Tags: windows, java, printing, printer

I am working a Java application on windows. Customer reports that printing is slow in the very first time after application restart.  It works fine in subsequent printing.

I used [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/) to find the bottle neck. Prblem is related to [a Java bug : getMediaPrintable which has a lot of overhead](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6722351)

I would like to see communication between printer and my application.  What tools I could use?